How to make the superuser appear in the SDDM user list?
I'd like to be able to log in as the superuser via SDDM without having to manually enter its username. I'd consequently like to have it appear amongst users (created via KDE Plasma 6's kcm_users).

This is not necessary and is generally discouraged as bad practice. Instead, you should state your use case (why you think you need root all the time) and ask for an approach that works in an unprivileged user session.
Programs that need to work on privileged resources
are already set up to use a privileged helper. 
For example, /sbin/gparted uses the helper pkexec on Debian.
Command-line programs do privilege bracketing and other protections. Graphical programs do not usually do this, and also have much more executable code, which makes for a larger attack surface.
The system policy is protecting you from

Security issues. For example, you download a specially crafted video, you open the folder, the file manager shows a preview / thumbnail,
and now malware has root.
Accidental breakage caused by a seemingly unimportant bug. 
For example, a text editor encounters a bug while manipulating the file path and overwrites the wrong file, breaking the current state of the machine, or the on-disk copy of the OS, or the hardware.

If you're not convinced yet, see also this blog post
from KDE developer Martin Flöser:

Today I pushed a change for Kate and KWrite which does no longer allow to be run as root. Instead it educates the user about how to do the same with sudoedit.
Now I understand that this will break the workflow for some users. But with a minor adjustment to your workflow you get the same. In fact it will be better, because the Kate you start is able to pick up your configured styling. And it will also work on Wayland. And most importantly it will be secure.


Also see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Running_GUI_applications_as_root and the quote by a GNOME developer, which also supports not running any GUI applications as root.

I'm aware of all of this. This isn't an X/Y problem - I solely use the superuser account to test how GUI applications cope with being run under that account. As you state, there is myriad advice online regarding how to avoid utilizing the account for standard operations, and with the recent adoption of PolicyKit, there is little which requires comprehensive elevation (except YaST). This, however, is irrelevant to my use case.
